# Implementing non-power-of-2 textures in Opengl

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es

I want to draw image as texture.My problem is that images size is non-power-of-2.
How can I draw this image.
Please suggest me.

Answer (score 3):

You can embed your non-power-of-2 image in a power-of-2 image file and use texture coordinates on vertices to specify which part of the image will be used as your texture. Read this [tutorial on textures](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/opengl/opengl-texture-mapping-an-introduction-r947) to learn more.

You can fill the remaining space in the image file with more "sub-images", if they fit, for use as further textures to avoid wasting space.

Comment: Note also that you can composite the non-power-of-2 images onto the power-of-2 texture object at runtime. This would allow you greater flexibility to reduce texture binds.

Comment: @ryanm You know, I never thought of that. That's a nice trick, I could generate custom tilesets on the fly!

Comment: Thanks for your support. My Image size was 1024 X 600. So first I converted it into 1024 X 1024 by filling remaining part with transparency using core graphics at run time. Now how I should I specify my texture coordinate to show only 1024X600 part of image.I am using const GLshort spriteTexcoords[] = {
    0, 0,
    1, 0,
    0, 1,
    1, 1,
}; as my texture coordinate now.Please help me.

Comment: A texture (i.e. the whole image file) has a size of 1x1. In your case, you will need to use a fraction of that size according to your desired sub-image: {0, 0, 1024.0 / 1024.0, 0, 0, 600.0 / 1024.0, 1024.0 / 1024.0, 600.0 / 1024.0} - See the edit above for a tutorial on textures.

Comment: When I do any such computation it show various vertical or horizontals lines.Where I am doing mistake?

Comment: I got my problem.It is working fine for me.

Comment: I got my problem.It is working fine for me.Thanks thanks waldrumpus for your support.